# Mysql error with OR AND

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table with the following data in table clients

```
------------------
|id|client|status|
------------------
|1 |331   |  0   |
|2 |331   |  1   |
|3 |331   |  2   |
|4 |331   |  1   |
|5 |331   |  0   |
|6 |222   |  0   |
------------------
```

I like to retrieve all the fields from the table clients where client is 331 and having status 0 or 1. That means I will be getting id 1,2,4,5 as the result.

But when i used this sql

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from clients where client=331 AND status=0 or status=1")
```

I am getting id 1,2,4,5,6 instead.

Whats the correct way to get the data?

Comment: BTW: Your query must be `select * from clients where client=331 AND status=1 or status=0` to get those results with your example data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
select * from clients where client=331 AND (status=0 or status=1)
```

The order of precedence for logical operators is (Not, And, then Or). As `And` has higher precedence than `Or` your query is effectively

```
select * from clients where (client=331 AND status=0) or status=1
```

Which is not the desired semantics. You could also use

```
select * from clients where client=331 AND status in (0,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parenthesis. Replace:

```
select * from clients where client=331 AND status=0 or status=1
```

with:

```
select * from clients where client=331 AND (status=0 or status=1)
```

- The first query looks for records which have either (client = 331 and status = 0), or status = 1.
- The second query looks for records which have client = 331 and either (status = 0 or status = 1).

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from clients where client=331 AND (status=0 or status=1)")
```

Your code reads "`if (client is 331 and status is 0) or (status is 1)`"

Answer (score 1):

Remember operator precedence!

Your criteria should be..
`client=331 AND (status=0 or status=1)`

or for completeness sake..

`client=331 AND status IN (0,1)`

Answer (score 0):

Parenthetic statements are your friend. SQL `AND` before `OR` as `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, to overcome this you need to use these things `( )`

You are looking for

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client=331 AND (status=0 OR status=1)
```

Comment: Not true that it will evaluate left to right. `AND` has higher precedence than `Or`. i.e. even if it was rewritten as `status=0 OR status=1 and client=331` it would still not return the correct results.